# If $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A=\begin{pmatrix}2 &5\\3&k\end{pmatrix}$,then one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is :-

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A=\begin{pmatrix}2 &5\\3&k\end{pmatrix}$,then one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is :-
$0,-1,1,2$

---

Can I get some hints please.

Comment: In which step you've stucked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(1,1)$ is an eigen vector.let $\lambda$ be corresponding eigen value.then
$\begin{pmatrix}2 &5\\3&k\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ solving you can get the values of $k$ and $\lambda$ and then it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

ans: -1
on solving above expression you'll get λ=7 & k=4 
put k=4 in given matrics and find the roots of characteristic equation......-1 will be one the roots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Although this answer is correct, it could used an improved write-up and formatting. just some friendly advice. Regards

Comment: thank you....for both welcome and suggestion.